# Icons don't appear ( Android Studio 4.1 )

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to add a new asset but my Android Studio isn't displaying my standard library of icons, which may be wrong? How to fix it ?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
   android {
             defaultConfig {
             vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
           }
           }

  dependencies {
             compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
           }
```

add these in your app.gradle and sync this